# PHP e javascript - Fazendo funcionar função onclick devidamente

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

Olá, sou desenvolvedor de uma página de um cliente.
Dentro dessa página, coloquei um link no cabeçalho (arquivo header.php) dentro de estrutura DIV que é assim:

```html
<div onclick="irParaMinhasReservas();" style="cursor: pointer;" id="btnMinhasReservas2" class="ph00_9"></div>
```

Por sugestão em outro fórum, defini a função `irParaMinhasReservas()` assim no arquivo principal.js:

```js
function irParaMinhasReservas(){
location.href = 'index.php?param=1'; }
```

Ou seja, quando eu tiver com a variável param definida, ele deverá ir pra página index.php e automaticamente abrir uma aba que existe lá dentro. O início da página index.php ficou assim:

```php
<?php
session_start("usuario");
if(isset($_GET['param'])){
    echo "<script>abreAba(2,logado);</script>";
}?>
```

Mas por enquanto não consegui fazer funcionar. O que eu posso ter feito errado ou possa ter esquecido nos códigos que defini?

Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: como não consegui entender exatamente onde está o Erro, e você não colocou informações adicionais sobre a sua paginas e scripts, tente substituit o `abreAba(2,logado)` por `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { abreAba(2,logado); }, false)`

Comment: Tens de colocar mais código e explicar a funcionalidade que pretendes, senão não vamos conseguir ajudar. O que queres fazer quando abrires a página `index.php`? onde está a função `abreAba`? e o que tem o resto do `index.php`?

Comment: A função abreAba está definida no arquivo index.js e serve pra abrir as abas que possuem na página index.php
O erro a princípio é que da forma que eu defini ele só me mostra o cabeçalho da página ao clicar nesse link e sem o resto da página index.

Comment: Tens de mostrar mais código para percebermos o que cada ficheiro tem...

Comment: A sugestão do TobyMosque funcionou. Peço desculpas, mas temo pelo meu cliente se eu revelar muitos códigos de página. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.